# More efficient way to write this small bit of Python code?

Tags: python, input

I've been going through a beginning Python book, and I've been trying to write a small block of code that will take users input, check to make sure it can be converted to an int and check if it's higher than 49152.

I know there's an easier way to do this, but I can't get my mind to figure it out.

```
port_input = raw_input("port(number must be higher than 49152: ")

check = True
while check == True:
    check = False
    try:
        port_number = int(port_input)
    except:
        port_input = raw_input("port(number must be higher than 49152: ")
        check = True

while int(port_input) < 49152:
    port_input = raw_input("Please enter a higher number(hint: more than 49152): ")
```

Comment: I'll put it here for you and for all answerers: [`except:` is considered harmful](http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html#except) except (no pun intended, really) in a few circumstances not met here.

Comment: @delnan:  Good point, and related: `except' should be for exceptions, not errors that can occur regularly.

Comment: @payne: EAFP is common, accepted and encouraged by the standard library (if you want to validate a stringly typed int without converting it to one via `int` and catching an exception, you have to roll the regex yourself or go with `str.isdigit` and disallow signs) in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have isn't functionaly correct anyway. Consider if someone puts "123" then "abc". The 123 will get them through the `while check` block, but when they get to the `while < 49152` block there's no checking.

Here's what I come up with (I don't do python, I just hacked it in based on your existing code...)

```
check = True
while check :
    port_input = raw_input("port(number must be higher than 49152: ")
    try:
        port_number = int(port_input)
        check = (port_number < 49152)
    except ValueError:
        check = True
```

Comment: [Don't compare boolean values to True or False using ==](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: @nmichaels Good point. Like I said, I just copied his code and tweaked it. I'll edit that in, because it's a good point that goes with all languages! ... fixed!

Comment: For someone who doesn't do Python that's pretty good :-) Two small points though - a plain 'except:' is very bad form, it should be 'except ValueError:' so you only catch the exception you're interested in and don't mask ones you weren't expecting. I would also move "check = (port_number < 49152)" to an "else:" clause on the try/except so it's clear that the ValueError you're catching comes from the int(port_number)

Comment: thank you so much for that.  I hadn't put much thought into make it fully functional, as it was just a passing thought I had while studying Python.  But I knew there had to be a more efficient way to write it.

Comment: @Downvoter - I'm curious as to why I was voted down. I'm always open to making improvements (both to my answers and to myself as a developer), so please let me know why it was DV'd! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the `check` flag if you wrap your code in a function:

```
def get_port():
    while True:
        port =  raw_input("port (number must be higher than 49152): ")
        try:
            port = int(port)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        if port > 49152:
            return port
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_input(msg = "port(number must be higher than 49152: "):
    port_input = raw_input(msg)
    try :
        if int(port_input) < 49152:
            return get_input("Please enter a higher number(hint: more than 49152): ")
    except ValueError:
        return get_input()
    return int(port_input)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return get_input()` so you don't lose the return value? I'm not a python guy so it might not be necessary, it's just what pops in my head. If it does work like you describe, would you mind explaining how? Thanks! :D

Comment: I forgot the return! Recursion is hard for me.

Comment: It wasn't even in a function, it was just a single block of code I was running. It's not something I will use, just a problem I thought of and wanted to solve.

Comment: I thought it would be simplier using a function and recursion then a infinite loop.

Comment: @fabio An interesting thought, but the recursion stack will eventually overflow. What if a user NEVER enters the correct answer? Should the program stack-overflow when it doesn't have to? :O

Comment: @glowcoder `try: inp = get_input(); except RuntimeError: print 'WTF?!?'`

Comment: @fabio something like that. But then it doesn't recur (recurse? I forget...) which is the whole fabric of the function. :O

Comment: @glowcoder You're right, my approach is limited you think about this

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 0

while n < 49152:
    try:
        n=int(raw_input("enter number heghier than 49152->"))
    except: 
        print "not integer!"

print "ok!"
```

Answer (score 1):

variant without using exception handling

```
def portInput(text):
    portInput.port_value = 0
    while True:
        port_input = raw_input(text)
        if not port_input.isdigit(): yield "port must be numeric"
        else:
            portInput.port_value = int(port_input)
            if portInput.port_value <= 49152: yield "number must be higher than 49152"
            else: return

for error in portInput("port(number must be higher than 49152): "):
    print error

print "entered port: %d" % portInput.port_value
```

Comment: Despite having the most upvotes on my answer, I really like this one. Avoiding exceptions when you can is a good thing!

Answer (score 0):

```
port = raw_input("port(number must be higher than 49152): ")
while not port.isdigit() or int(port) <= 49152:
    print("port must be a number > 49152")
    port = input("port(number must be higher than 49152): ")
```

The `int(port)` call is only done when `not port.isdigit()` is False -> port contains of digits. This is because the second operand for the `or` operator is only evaluated if the first is False.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to avoid code duplication and make things a bit more pythonic with this rendition. Notice that I do not 'except:' but instead specifically catch ValueError. Often people forget that 'except:' also catches the SyntaxError exception which can make hunting down a stupid typo extremely frustrating. I assumed the port number here is a TCP or UDP port number and thus make sure it is also less than 65536.

```
have_valid_input = False

while not have_valid_input:
    unsafe_port = raw_input('port: ')
    try:
        port_number = int(unsafe_port)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        if port_number > 49152 and port_number < 65536:
            have_valid_input = True

    if not have_valid_input:
        print 'Invalid port'

print 'port', port_number
```

Comment: Your example prints `Invalid port` even when the result is good on the first try.